# What is Python doing when I'm trying to read a binary file?

Tags: python, arrays, binary, byte

Say I have a file named "font" with no extension. The contents of "font" are(when viewed by Sublime Text):

```
774f 4646 0001 0000 0000 7bac 0011 0000
0000 e148 0001 0000 0000 7650 0000 055c
0000 0a6a 0000 0000 0000 0000 4750 4f53
0000 0180 0000 078b 0000 218a b149 b3e5
```

I have the Python code:

```
with open('font', 'rb') as f:
    bytes = f.read()
    print(bytes)
```

Which prints:

```
b'wOFF\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00{\xac\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe1H\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00vP\x00\x00\x05\\\x00\x00\nj\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00GPOS\x00\x00\x01\x80\x00\x00\x07\x8b\x00\x00!\x8a\xb1I\xb3\xe5'
```

Why is Python:

1. Decoding some bytes to ASCII(`774f464->wOFF`)
2. Returning things like extra backslashes, capital letters, letters outside of the hexadecimal range, brackets, exclamation points, 6 digit hex "bytes", etc.

And how should I obtain my expected result, which is:

```
\x77\x4f\x46\x46\x00\x01...
```

Comment: No. It's binary, e.g., file tool returns "data"

Comment: I don't want a string of hex, i want an object I can interface with like the bytes type.

Comment: The raw data (integers) are being interpreted/displayed/converted to/as their string equivalents for printing.

Comment: `data` is a bytes *type*.

Comment: `...I can interface...` - what do you want to *do* with it. - maybe `new=array.array('b',data)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `hex string` from bytes use `bytes_data.hex()`:

```
data = b'wOFF\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00{\xac\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe1H\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00vP\x00\x00\x05\\\x00\x00\nj\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00GPOS\x00\x00\x01\x80\x00\x00\x07\x8b\x00\x00!\x8a\xb1I\xb3\xe5'
print(data.hex())
```

Output is:

```
774f46460001000000007bac001100000000e14800010000000076500000055c00000a6a000000000000000047504f53000001800000078b0000218ab149b3e5
```